# What's the easiest way to have a timed callback in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I want to do something like this in C# (more specifically, WPF):

```
Thread.Invoke(MyCallback, 1000);
```

Which will just call MyCallback, 1 time, 1 second from now.

What is the easiest way to do this with .NET?  Do I have to setup a Timer and hook an event?

Comment: Is it just me or has there been a flood of `Timer`-related questions lately?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [System.Timers.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx) to do this without spawning your own thread.  Implement the [Elapsed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.elapsed.aspx) callback to do what you want, setting `Enabled` true and `AutoReset` false to achieve a single invocation.

Make sure you `Dispose` the `Timer` object once you are done with it!

Comment: I'd be interested in seeing code that wrapped this up as a method that took an action and delay.

Comment: Sorry @George, I don't have such a canned wrapper to hand.

Comment: @George I and at least one other answerer have posted possible implementations.

Comment: @Jay, and they're much appreciated. I posted that comment when there were none. :)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a method that runs an [Action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action.aspx) after a certain timeout using a [Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx):

```
static void Invoke(TimeSpan dueTime, Action action)
{
    Timer timer = null;
    timer = new Timer(_ => { timer.Dispose(); action(); });
    timer.Change(dueTime, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(-1));
}
```

I'm not sure how lightweight exactly a Timer is, but it should be better than blocking a ThreadPool thread.

Usage:

```
Invoke(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), () =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    // Do Stuff
});
```

As noted in comments below, although easy to understand and short to write, this is a relatively inefficient/resource hungry way of doing this.

Comment: I don't think it's that bad, it won't really use many resources and the thread waiting won't use CPU time. I'd *guess* a timer would use more resources.

Comment: I have a utility wrapper that uses System.Threading.Timer, but this is a reasonably clean way to do it.  It blocks a thread-pool thread, as Kirk mentions, so you wouldn't want to use it if you are using this pattern in many places.  In the worst case, you can starve the thread pool (especially if you have long delays) and your callbacks will execute much later than you expect.

Comment: Even an idle thread uses 1MB of virtual memory by default; there's no point using a chunk of address space on doing nothing. And given that overall thread pool threads are limited, there's no point having a thread doing nothing for a second when it could be doing something else.

Comment: @Dan, that's true, didn't think about the threadpool running out of threads etc. Does the `Timer` use windows messaging or something do avoid this kind of thing (using a thread)?

Comment: Ok @Dan, @Tim, @Kirk. I stand corrected, my answer definately isn't the best way (will edit answer). Luckly OP asked for easiest way. :P

Comment: @George, the OS typically has special support for registering timer callbacks, as this is such a common requirement in programs.  The .NET BCL also has a Timer that uses the message pump, but its main purpose is just to make sure the callbacks occur on the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

Usage:

```
Delay.Invocation(MyCallback, 1000);

//or

Delay.Invocation(() => MyCallbackWithArgs(arg1, arg2), 1000);
```

Wrapper:

```
public class Delay
{
    readonly Timer _timer;
    readonly Action _action;

    private Delay(Action action, double delayMilliseconds)
    {
        _action = action;
        _timer = new Timer(delayMilliseconds);
        _timer.Elapsed += ExecuteCallback;
    }

    void ExecuteCallback(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        _timer.Stop();
        _timer.Elapsed -= ExecuteCallback;
        _timer.Dispose();

        _action();
    }

    void Begin()
    {
        _timer.Start();
    }

    public static void Invocation(Action action, int delayMilliseconds)
    {
        var delay = new Delay(action, delayMilliseconds);
        delay.Begin();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just my 2 cents,

```
public class WaitableWorker
    {
        private readonly System.Threading.Timer timer;
        public WaitableWorker(int interval, Action callback, bool blocking = false)
        {
            if (blocking)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(interval);
                callback();
            }
            else
            {
                timer = new System.Threading.Timer(_ =>
                                                       {
                                                           timer.Dispose();
                                                           callback();
                                                       },
                                                   null, interval, Timeout.Infinite);
            }
        }

    }
```

**Usage**

```
 WaitableWorker worker=new WaitableWorker(3000,DoWork);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you've got the [Reactive Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609), you can do this:

```
Observable.Return(true)
    .Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
    .Subscribe(_ => DoWork());
```